# update table in sorted order

Tags: sqlite

I am maintaining table structure like below.

```
sortid | id | name
   1   | 1  | aa
   3   | 2  | cc
   4   | 3  | cc
   2   | 4  | bb
   5   | 5  | dd
```

Where sortid is maintained according to ascending order of name.
Now I want to update name 'dd' to 'aa', such way that sort id is also updated to its correct value.

```
Update table set name="bb" where name like "dd";
```

After updating my table should become like below.

```
sortid | id | name
   1   | 1  | aa
   4   | 2  | cc
   5   | 3  | cc
   3   | 4  | bb
   2   | 5  | aa
```

Comment: Table rows have no sort order. `SortId` is just a number you could update to anything you want. In fact, a SQL statement could return the rows in whatever order it wanted unless you specified an `ORDER BY` statement

Comment: The question is how can I update sortid in single statement?

Answer (score 0):

That `sortid` is the number of rows that would be sorted before this row.

So you can compute it by counting rows:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET sortid = (SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM MyTable AS T2
              WHERE T2.name < MyTable.name) +
             (SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM MyTable AS T2
              WHERE T2.name = MyTable.name
                AND T2.id <= MyTable.id);
```

(The second subquery resolves duplicate `sortid` values that would result from duplicate names.)

Comment: Isn't it complex? Because it is doing two string comparison for every entry with all the entries.

Comment: This is the *least* complex answer of all the answers so far.